# check if field property exist if does not remove it from object array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have array type object in javascript, i want to check if field property exist if does not remove it from object array 
for example the array that i have is

```
var array = [{ 0:Common_Text_Area__c:"test 1"
  Evaluation__c:"a0W2F000000xB6sUAE"
  Id:"a0u2F000000ocv0QAA"
  Name:"ER-003346"
  Rating_Owner__c:"Employee"
  Review_Question__c:"a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"
1:Evaluation__c:"a0W2F000000xB6sSDE"
  Id:"a0u2F058254ocv0QAA"
  Name:"ER-013346"
  Rating_Owner__c:"Employee"
  Review_Question__c:"a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"}]
```

I want to check Common_Text_Area__c exist if it does not then remove it all so I will end up with this in my array

```
    var arrayTwo = [{ 0:Common_Text_Area__c:"test 1"
     Evaluation__c:"a0W2F000000xB6sUAE"
     Id:"a0u2F000000ocv0QAA"
     Name:"ER-003346"
     Rating_Owner__c:"Employee"
     Review_Question__c:"a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"}]
```

Comment: use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative with functions `filter` and `includes`.

```js
var array = [{    'Common_Text_Area__c': "test 1",    'Evaluation__c': "a0W2F000000xB6sUAE",    Id: "a0u2F000000ocv0QAA",    Name: "ER-003346",    'Rating_Owner__c': "Employee",    'Review_Question__c': "a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"  },  {    'Evaluation__c': "a0W2F000000xB6sSDE",    Id: "a0u2F058254ocv0QAA",    Name: "ER-013346",    'Rating_Owner__c': "Employee",    'Review_Question__c': "a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"  }];

console.log(array.filter(o => Object.keys(o).includes('Common_Text_Area__c')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If the value of `Common_Text_Area__c` will be different than `undefined`, `null`, Etc you can use Destructuring assignment.

```js
var array = [{    'Common_Text_Area__c': "test 1",    'Evaluation__c': "a0W2F000000xB6sUAE",    Id: "a0u2F000000ocv0QAA",    Name: "ER-003346",    'Rating_Owner__c': "Employee",    'Review_Question__c': "a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"  },  {    'Evaluation__c': "a0W2F000000xB6sSDE",    Id: "a0u2F058254ocv0QAA",    Name: "ER-013346",    'Rating_Owner__c': "Employee",    'Review_Question__c': "a0w2F000000OoH5QAK"  }];

console.log(array.filter(({Common_Text_Area__c}) => Common_Text_Area__c));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return an array with just the elements that pass a test. Use the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to test if an object has a property:

```
const result = arr.filter( obj => 'Common_Text_Area__c' in obj );
```